# How to set tableview cell height equal to the table view that contains it in Swift 4.0

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` inside of a `cell`, and that `UITableView` always show one row. 
I need the `height` of that row to always be 100% of the `height` of the `tableview` that contains it.

I try this:

`tableView.rowHeight = tableView.frame.height`

In the `awakeFromNib()` func of the `cell` that contains the `UITableView`. 
But does not work, the row be showed with ~75% of the `UITableView` `heigth`.

Any other ideas?

Problem:  https://ibb.co/m0gwcNS

Comment: Having is a tableview inside another tableView is not at all recommended. Couldn't a UIView do the trick for you? Nevertheless, in order to change cell height you need to access heightForRowAt indexpath method.

Comment: The tableview are inside of a collectionViewCell, its kinda weird, but i need it.

Comment: Are you using autolayout in the tableviewcell?

Comment: if your tableView is inside a collection then your issue is in constraints , no difference between `rowHeight` and `heightForRowAt` BTW